# combine two dynamic variable into one to output single result - typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to merge or combine two variables into one new variable.

My Snippet looks like this:

in TS(component) file

```
this.setTextLang='_pt';
```

In HTML

`<div *ngFor="let el of exlists">
     <ion-label>
        {{el.menu_name+(setTextLang) }}
     </ion-label>
</div>`

But this didn't work, of course.

Present output:(it concatenates the output - this I am not expecting)

```
 USA_pt
 Nepal_pt
```

### `Expecting output`

Compiler should understand `{{el.menu_name+(setTextLang) }}` as  `{{el.menu_name_pt }}` & give the value of `el.menu_name_pt` inside `*ngFor` :

Does anybody have other solution for me? Much thanks in advance!
If my question is not clear, please let me know

Comment: Please see my answer with demo, and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I think I see your problem now.

Bracketed property access as @Simonare correctly pointed out would be the natural solution. However, that won't work for this use case due to the limitation of Angular template syntax. Inside the '{{}}' template syntax, you cannot evaluate a string variable inside a bracket accessor.

Bascially, you cannot do `{{el['menuName' + setTextLang]}}` because 'setTextLang' cannot be evaluated in that scope.

So, one possible solution would be to have a helper method in your model do the accessing for you:

```
getProperty(obj: any, property: string): string {
  return obj[property + this.setTextLang];
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let el of exlists">
  <div>{{getProperty(el, 'menuName')}}</div>  
</div>
```

Here's a stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an2xiz